# Read text file into several lists line by line

Tags: python, string, text, readline

If we have a text file as follows:

```
６   &   ロク３ &   サン
９   &   キュウ
０   &   ゼロ５ &   ゴ
７   &   ナナみぎ    &   ミギひだり   &   ヒダリ
うえ  &   ウエ
```

How could one read it into python to get a list for each "column" in a way such as this:

```
a = ["6", "9", "0", "7", "うえ"]
b = ["ロク３" , "キュウ", "ゼロ５", "ナナみぎ", "ウエ"]
c = ["サン", "", "ゴ}", "ミギひだり", ""]
d = ["", "ヒダリ", "", "", ""]
```

Comment: split and append to separate list, then print those lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
with open(path, 'r') as inputFile:
    lines = list()

    for line in inputFile:
        lines.append(line.split("&"))

    maxLen = len(max(lines, key=lambda x: len(x)))

    for line in lines:
        while len(line) < maxLen:
            line.append(" ")

    column0 = [line[0] for line in lines]
    column1 = [line[1] for line in lines]
    .
    .
    .
```

In addition, if you want to get rid of the blank spaces in your "cells", use the `replace` method:

```
without_spaces = with_spaces.replace(" ", "")
```

To use it, just replace

```
lines.append(line.split("&"))
```

with

```
lines.append(line.replace(" ", "").split("&"))
```

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) would be very convenient for the task.

```
import itertools

def cleanup(alist):
    return [item.strip() for item in alist]

with open('input.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    lines = input_file.readlines()
    contents = [cleanup(line.split('&')) for line in lines]
    zipped = itertools.izip_longest(*contents, fillvalue='')

    for column in zipped:
        print column
```

Notice that `zipped` is actually an iterator for all columns.